# Can the transpose of cropped block-Toeplitz matrix be represented as a cropped 2D convolution?

Tags: matrices, convolution, neural-networks, toeplitz-matrices, vectorization

Suppose we have the following matrices defined over the field of complex numbers ($\Bbb C$):

- a square input matrix $\mathbf{U}$ with dimensions $n \times n$
- a *symmetric* convolution kernel $\mathbf{H}$ with dimensions $k \times k$.
- a square output matrix of convolution $\mathbf{V} =  \mathbf{H} * \mathbf{U}$ with dimensions $(n+k-1) \times (n+k-1)$.

It is known that there is an equivalence between the 2D convolution and matrix-vector multiplication with the **block**-Toeplitz matrix. More specifically, there exists a block-Toeplitz matrix $\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{H})$ satisfying the relationship

$$ 
\texttt{vec}(\mathbf{V}) = \mathbf{T}(\mathbf{H}) \texttt{vec}(\mathbf{U}) = \texttt{vec}(\mathbf{H}*\mathbf{U})
$$

where $\texttt{vec}(\mathbf{U}),\texttt{vec}(\mathbf{V})$ are the vectorized forms of the input and output matrices.

Next, lets suppose we crop the output of the convolution to have the same dimensions as the input. The crop operation can be represented as matrix multiplication with a binary matrix $\mathbf{C}$ having dimensions $n^2 \times (n+k-1)^2$ such that

$$
\texttt{vec}(\mathbf{V}_{c}) = \mathbf{C}\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{H})\texttt{vec}(\mathbf{U}) = \texttt{vec}(\texttt{crop}(\mathbf{H}*\mathbf{U}))
$$

Finally we arrive at the question:

Can the matrix-vector operation involving the transpose of the Cropped Toeplitz matrix $(\mathbf{C}\mathbf{T})^{T}$ be represented as a cropped convolution? Mathematically, can we say that

$$
(\mathbf{C}\mathbf{T})^{T} \texttt{vec}(\mathbf{U}) = \texttt{vec}(\texttt{crop}(\mathbf{H' * \mathbf{U}}))
$$

for some new kernel $\mathbf{H}'$?

---

**Motivation**

This question stems from the implementation of a physics-based [diffractive neural network](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.aat8084). If the relationship above holds, I think it would immensely speed up [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) and reduce the space complexity.

Comment: Please use DOI links whenever possible.

Comment: Is $\bf C$ unique?  You could provide the $\bf C$ matrix that makes my $9 \times 4$ matrix square

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the matrix $\bf U$ is $n \times n$ and that the matrix $\bf H$ is $m \times m$. Thus, the matrix ${\bf V} := {\bf H} \ast {\bf U}$ produced via $2$-dimensional [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) is $(m + n - 1) \times (m + n - 1)$. There is a matrix-valued function

$${\bf T} : {\Bbb R}^{m \times m} \to {\Bbb R}^{(m + n - 1)^2 \times n^2}$$

such that

$$ \operatorname{vec} ({\bf Y}) = {\bf T} ({\bf H}) \operatorname{vec} ({\bf U}) $$

where $\operatorname{vec}$ denotes the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) operator. Transposing, we could write $ {\bf T}^\top ({\bf H}) \operatorname{vec} ({\bf U}) $, which is utter nonsense because the dimensions do **not** match. Please refine your question.

---

**Example**

Let $m = n = 2$. Hence, $m + n - 1 = 3$. Note that the $9 \times 4$ matrix

$$ {\bf T} ({\bf H}) = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}h_{22} & & & \\ h_{12} & h_{22} &  & \\ & h_{12} & & \\ \hline h_{21} & & h_{22} & \\ h_{11} & h_{21} & h_{12} & h_{22} \\ & h_{11} & & h_{12} \\ \hline & & h_{21} & \\ & & h_{11} & h_{21} \\ & & & h_{11} \end{array}\right] $$

is **block**-Toeplitz rather than plain vanilla [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix). Again, please refine your question.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Matlab's [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)

Comment: thank you very much for catching the ambiguities in the question! I have since tried to make the problem more well-defined and have adopted your notation:) Doing so has given me more to think about so I'll continue working to solve it in the meantime. If there are any remaining issues I'd be happy to make more edits to the post.

Comment: there were some small tweaks to notation I had to make for clarity. The revisions should now be stable. Thank you.